# Check the following Relation $R=\{(x,y) |\exists k\in \mathbb{Z} \cdot x*y=3k \}$

Tags: logic, relations

I would like to check the following relation:
$$R=\{(x,y) |\exists k\in \mathbb{Z} \cdot x*y=3k \},R\subseteq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$$

1. Reflexivity
2. Symmetric
3. Transitivity
4. Asymmetric

Can I write a matrix for this relation? its possible?
What is an element in this relation? $(x,y)$ is $1$ element? for example if I want to check relexivity what should I take? $(x,y)R(x,y)$? OR $(x,x)R(x,x)$?
Suggestions are welcomed! Thanks.

Comment: What numbers are the $x,y$? Real, rational, natural etc? It's $xRy$ btw (so for reflexivity, check $xRx$.

Comment: Its Reflexivity? because there is $k$ that $x*y=3k$ right? for example $k=3 \rightarrow 3*3=3*3$ this is the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\left(1,1\right)\notin R$. This shows that $R$ not reflexive.

We have $xy=yx$ so if $xy=3k$ then also $yx=3k$. This shows that
$R$ is symmetric.

We have $\left(1,3\right)\in R$ and $\left(3,1\right)\in R$ but
not $\left(1,1\right)\in R$. This shows that $R$ is not transitive.

We have $\left(1,3\right)\in R$ but not $\left(3,1\right)\notin R$.
This shows that $R$ is not asymmetric.

I don't know what a matrix for a relation is, so cannot help you here.

Comment: What about Anti-Symetric? its not, right?

Comment: Indeed it's not. We have $(3,1)\in R$ and $(1,3)\in R$ but are not allowed to conclude that $1=3$

Comment: Asymmetric if: $\left(x,y\right)\in R\Rightarrow\left(y,x\right)\notin R$.
Antisymmetric if $\left(x,y\right)\in R\wedge\left(y,x\right)\in R\Rightarrow x=y$

Comment: how should I represent $R^2$ it will be transitivity?

Comment: Transitivity of $R$ if: $(x,y)\in R \wedge (y,z)\in R\rightarrow (x,z)\in R$. You are talking about $R^2$, but I don't think that's relevant here. You have $(x,z)\in R^2$ iff some $y$ exists with $(x,y)\in R\wedge (y,z)\in R$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

1. It is not reflexive.
   $$
   (1,1) \notin R \because 1*1 = 1 \neq 3k \ (k \in \mathbb{Z})
   $$
2. It is symmetric.
   $$
   (x,y) \in R \implies x*y = 3k \ (k \in \mathbb{Z}) \implies y*x = 3k \implies (y,x) \in R.
   $$
3. It is not transitive.
   $$
   (1,3) \in R, (3,7) \in R \ \ \text{but} \ (1,7) \notin R
   $$
4. It is not asymmetric.
   $$
   (1,3), (3,1) \in R
   $$

Comment: You proved that the relation is not 'antisymmetric'. The OP asked for 'asymmetric'.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The relation is a relation on $\Bbb Z$, this means that we want to ask whether or not $3\mathrel{R}3$, rather than asking $(3,3)\mathrel{R}(3,3)$.

As for a matrix, you probably can't, on the count that this is an infinite matrix, and you won't have time to finish it, or matter to write on (and with) the entire matrix. But it is probably worth a shot writing it for a few elements (look at the relation restricted to four-five elements).

Doing so is likely to give you the counterexample needed for reflexivity, asymmetry and transitivity, and might give you a hunch as to why this is a transitive relation.